# Can I use a capacitor which has 275v +-10% tolerance in a 9V circuit?

Tags: capacitor, dc, circuit-design, electricity, guitar-pedal

I am trying to get parts for a circuit i want to make and I'm very new at making circuits. As a result i'm unsure if i can use a 150nF capacitor with 275v+-10% tolerance in the following circuit or whether i need a different tolerance or anything. As far as I know the 9V in will be DC.[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: No problem for rating to exceeding the voltage limits of a circuit.

Comment: so as long as its below the tolerance its fine then? doesnt have to be within the 10% range?

Comment: Fine if you can live with the +/-10%, you will find that lower capacitance often goes hand-in-hand with higher voltage.

Comment: "doesnt have to be within the 10% range?": +-10% relates to the capacitance, not the voltage. Due to production tolerances it can be somewhere between 135-165nF.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! Diagrams like the one you have shown are difficult to follow. In the future, please draw a schematic instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any capacitor has four basic ratings:

1) Rated capacitance (in Farads, named after Micheal Faraday)

2) Manufacturing tolerance (in percentage of rated Farads)

3) Voltage (maximum) -- the highest voltage that can be applied without destroying the capacitor.

4) Temperature (primarily used only for electrolytic capacitors), typically this is related to (substantially below) the boiling point of the liquid electrolyte.

A further property of capacitors is 'leakage' -- but this is largely a function of the type of capacitor and is not a 'rating' within given types.

The combination of Farads and Voltage tells you how much electrical charge can be stored in the capacitor.  Higher voltage capacitors (of similar type) will be physically larger than lower voltage capacitors.